# Synchronous execution for node.js program using 'readline'

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, readline, synchronous

I'm having some problems getting the asynchronous nature of node to co-operate with me, and after hours of callbacks and googling; I finally turn to you guys.

I have a program that needs to read in lines from a file using the readline module of node. This file contains data that is passed to some asynchronous functions defined within my node program. Once all the data is successfully read and processed, this data needs to be parsed into JSON format, and then outputted.

My problem here is that when I call: `readLine.on('close', function() { ...... }`, this is run before the asynchronous functions finish running, and therefore I am left with an output of nothing, but the program keeps running the asynchronous functions.

I've created a simple skeleton of functions that should explain my situation more clearly:

```
function firstAsyncFunc(dataFromFile) {
   //do something asynchronously

   return processedData;
}


function secondAsyncFunc(dataFromFile) {
  //do something else asynchronously

  return processedData;
}


//create readline 
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('data.txt')
});


//array to hold all the data processed
var totalDataStorage; 


//read file 
lineReader.on('line', function(line) {

  var processedData = firstAsyncFunction(line);
  var moreProcessedData = secondAsyncFunction(line);


  //store processed data and concatenate into one array
  var tempDataStorage = [{ 'first': processedData, 'second': moreProcessedData }]
  totalDataStorage = totalDataStorage.concat(tempDataStorage);

}).on('close', function() {

  var JSONString = JSON.stringify(... //create JSON for totalDataStorage ...);
  console.log(JSONString); //DOESN'T OUTPUT ANYTHING!

});
```

I have tried to add a callback to the first/secondAsynFunction, I have tried to make the reading and parsing bit of the program seperate functions, and create callbacks so that parsing is only called when reading finished, but none of those solutions seemed to be working and i'm really struggling - so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: The data.txt file is of the form

```
IPData1 DataCenter1
IPData2 DataCenter2
...
IPDataN DataCenterN
```

I use str.split(" ") to get the respective values, and then pass them appropriately. IPData is a number, and DataCenter is a string

Comment: can you share the data.txt file? i believe i can answer you

Comment: @JaromandaX See again OP's code. It is an array, not string.

Comment: The data.txt file is of the form: `IPData, DataCentre`.  In the actual program, I use str.split(" "), to split the two values, and then pass them into the necessary function. The IPData is a number, and the DataCentre value is a string. Hope this helps

Comment: @OliverOstach You have a lot of mistakes in your code. You need to realize that every time you call an asynchronous function, it doesn't return a value and you need to pass a callback function too. Your line `var processedData = firstAsyncFunction(line);` makes no sense at all. Also, it can be done very easily in a few rows using `fs.readFile`.

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention that the async functions return values! String values to be precise! I'll edit that in now

Comment: @OliverOstach If it returns a value, it is not asynchronous anymore.

Comment: I'd suggest googling `event driven programming` and doing some reading.  It appears you don't understand the basic flow of actions with event driven programming which the `lineReader` object is all about.  You set up a bunch of event handlers, then you start the operation and you let it trigger various events.  You don't call close.  You register and event handler for that event and the system creates that event at the right time and calls your handler for it.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous functions do not return a value, but you must pass a callback function to it instead. Your line

> var processedData = firstAsyncFunction(line);

doesn't make sense at all. If your `data.txt` file looks like this

```
IPData1 DataCenter1
IPData2 DataCenter2
IPData3 DataCenter3
```

you can read data as following

```
var fs = require('fs');
var rl = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('data.txt')
});
var arr = [];

rl.on('line', a => {
  a = a.split(' ');
  arr.push({
    first: a[0],
    second: a[1]
  });
}).on('close', () => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2));
});
```

It will log

```
[
  {
    "first": "IPData1",
    "second": "DataCenter1"
  },
  {
    "first": "IPData2",
    "second": "DataCenter2"
  },
  {
    "first": "IPData3",
    "second": "DataCenter3"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately this doesn't work. I've registered a callback function to 'return' results from the async functions, and then called them appropriately from within the `lineReader.on('line', ...)`, but I am still having the same issue of `.on('close')`, running **BEFORE** the async functions have finished and returned the result.. (this was my issue,  I've been able to verify that i'm doing everything else correct!)

Comment: @OliverOstach You simply can't understand how asynchronous functions work. By definition, asynchronous function **CANNOT** return a value, so stop calling it asynchronous. If it returns a value, then it **MUST** run before `onClose` event is fired, because it is the way `v8` engine works. How do you think my answer doesn't work? Did you try it? Copy-paste it to ensure it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following and its working locally.

1. use promises to make your life easier.
2. remove .close since you dont have an output defined in the interface.

> The 'close' event is emitted when one of the following occur:
>
> 1. The rl.close() method is called and the readline.Interface instance has relinquished control over the input and output streams;
> 2. The input stream receives its 'end' event;
> 3. The input stream receives -D to signal end-of-transmission (EOT);
> 4. The input stream receives -C to signal SIGINT and there is no SIGINT event listener registered on the readline.Interface instance.

```
function firstAsyncFunc(dataFromFile) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //do something asynchronously
    resolve(result);
  })
}

function secondAsyncFunc(dataFromFile) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //do something asynchronously
    resolve(result);
  })
}

//create readline 
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('data.txt')
});

//array to hold all the data processed
var totalDataStorage;

//read file 
lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
  Promise.all([
      firstAsyncFunc(line),
      secondAsyncFunc(line)
    ])
    .then(function(results) {
      var tempDataStorage = [{
        'first': results[0],
        'second': results[1]
      }];
      // i'd use push instead of concat
      totalDataStorage = totalDataStorage.concat(tempDataStorage);
    });
})
```

Comment: This seems like it could work, but I just can't seem to figure out where I would log the data such that all the asynchnorous functions would have been executed by the logging stage